Twilio Streaming Latency on Outgoing calls only
I'm using Google speech to text or deepgram to test this , both give me the same result.
When I perform a twilio call I'm getting a really weird behavior sometimes.
Like the audio is being repeated multiple times for no reason, IDK if it's the way I'm handling the websocket or sending the audio.
When I get the response from deepgram or google speech it comes like this:
It may seem that I said all of that really fast and at the same time, but that is not the case, when I speak I give it about 5 second stop between each sentence, and they are being returned as if I spoke all at the same time.
This happens only in 40% of the calls , the others work as intended.
non final: hello what's your name
non final: hello what's your name can
non final: hello what's your name can you
non final: hello what's your name can you hear
non final: hello what's your name can you hear me
non final: hello what's your name can you hear me hello
non final: hello what's your name can you hear me hello
non final: hello what's your name can you hear me hello
non final: hello what's your name can you hear me hello
non final: hello what's your name can you hear me hello are
non final: hello what's your name can you hear me hello are you
non final: hello what's your name can you hear me hello are you there
non final: hello what's your name can you hear me hello are you there
non final: hello what's your name can you hear me hello are you there hello
non final: hello what's your name can you hear me hello are you there hello
non final: hello what's your name can you hear me hello are you there hello bro
non final: hello what's your name can you hear me hello are you there hello bro
non final: hello what's your name can you hear me hello are you there hello bro
non final: hello what's your name can you hear me hello are you there hello bro
non final: hello what's your name can you hear me hello are you there hello bro what
non final: hello what's your name can you hear me hello are you there hello bro what
non final: hello what's your name can you hear me hello are you there hello bro what the
non final: hello what's your name can you hear me hello are you there hello bro what the
non final: hello what's your name can you hear me hello are you there hello bro what the hell
non final: hello what's your name can you hear me hello are you there hello bro what the hell
non final: hello what's your name can you hear me hello are you there hello bro what the hell is
non final: hello what's your name can you hear me hello are you there hello bro what the hell is 

The code above created the call:
@application.post('/make-call')  # receive phone call request
async def make_call(call_requests: List[CallRequest]):
    
    for call_request in call_requests:
        # Twilio credentials
        TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN = get_twilio_keys(university_id=call_request.university_id)

        # Initialize Twilio client
        client = Client(TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN)
        await upload_lead(phone=call_request.to,name=call_request.name,
                    course=call_request.course,language=call_request.language,
                    country=call_request.country,code=call_request.code,
                    university_id=call_request.university_id)

        phone_number = get_available_phone_number(call_request.university_id)
        if phone_number:
            URL = f"https://{PUBLIC_URL}/call"
            STATUS_URL = f"https://{PUBLIC_URL}/status-call"
            client.calls.create(
                method='POST',
                #status_callback=STATUS_URL,
                #status_callback_method='POST',
                url=URL,
                to=call_request.to,
                from_=phone_number
            )
        else:
            response = {"Message": f"No available phone numbers for university ID: {call_request.university_id}"}
            return JSONResponse(response, status_code=409)

Above IS the code that receives the request from above and created the stream, this is also used when getting incoming calls:
#init connection with web socket
@application.post('/call')#Make Phone Call OUTGOING
async def handle_incoming_calls(request: Request, From: Annotated[str, Form()],To: Annotated[str, Form()]):
    response = VoiceResponse()
    connect = Connect()

    URL = f"wss://{PUBLIC_URL}/stream"
    connect.stream(url=URL)
    response.append(connect)
    return Response(content=str(response), media_type='text/xml')


That Function Will send the stream to stream endpoint which will hadle the websockets:
@application.websocket('/stream')
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):

    await websocket.accept()

    while True:
        await wait_for_user_input(websocket)

Deepgram Wait for user input:
#init deepram
def deepgram_init():
    config = DeepgramClientOptions(
            options={"keepalive": "true"}
        )
    deepgram_client = DeepgramClient(api_key=DEEPGRAM_API_KEY,config=config)
    return deepgram_client.listen.live.v("1")


async def wait_for_user_input(websocket: WebSocket,lang,messages,voice_id,voice_model,university_name,university_phone,student_phone,university_id,student_data,listen_task):
    # Event to signal when transcript is ready
    

    dg_connection = deepgram_init()
    
    transcript_ready_event = asyncio.Event()
    transcript = None

    def on_message(self, result, **kwargs):
        nonlocal transcript_ready_event
        nonlocal transcript
        sentence = result.channel.alternatives[0].transcript
        if len(sentence) == 0:
            return
        is_final = result.is_final
        if is_final:
            transcript = sentence
            print(f"TRANSCRIPT: {transcript}")
        else:
            print(f"Non final: {sentence}")

    dg_connection.on(LiveTranscriptionEvents.Transcript, on_message)


    options: LiveOptions = LiveOptions(
            model="nova-2",
            punctuate=False,
            language=lang,
            encoding="mulaw",
            channels=1,
            sample_rate=8000,
            # To get UtteranceEnd,
            interim_results=True,
            utterance_end_ms="1000",
            vad_events=True
        )
    dg_connection.start(options)

    while True:
        message = await websocket.receive_text()

        msg = json.loads(message)

        if msg['event'] == 'start':
            call_sid = msg['start']['callSid']
        elif msg['event'] == 'media':
            media = msg['media']
            audio = base64.b64decode(media['payload'])
            dg_connection.send(audio)
                

I tried to use different STT solutions and I face the same issue with all of them.
#NOTE. The issue only happens in outgoing calls , incoming calls work perfectly, I also listen to the live audio and when the issue occurs the audio is also corrupted .
